# При запуске приложения вылетает ошибка NullPointerException LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

Я не понимаю в чем проблема использую LibGDX для создания игры, подключил библиотеку InputMultiplexer для того чтобы отслеживать два касания по экрану и перемещать игрока, создал 2 класса для реализации интерфейса InputProcessor, чтобы потом передать их InputMultiplexer-у и перехватывать одно касание для ходьбы, а другое для прыжка, но при касании вылетает ошибка NullPointerException, как мне ее решить?
Система: Kubuntu 19.10
Движок: LibGDX
IDE: Android Studio

[image: Код где возникает ошибка]

[image: Сама ошибка]

Comment: Не нужно писать такие длинные условия, вынесите его компоненты на отдельные строки, тогда станет понятнее, где же там null, ну или используйте отладчик.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Попробовал разделить условие как вы и сказали, понял что ошибка на 35 строчке кода, вот сам код с разделенным условием [tochDown](https://imgur.com/GP3DyNS) вот ошибка [Ошибка](imgur.com/lhzj65G). В итоге сделал вот так [Код](https://imgur.com/rncHvia) просто передал в один из классов InputProcessor объект player и внутри класса в конструкторе получил его [Конструктор](https://imgur.com/wmNoIou) и теперь все работает. Спасибо большое)))